# Flutter Web : Custom DatePicker inside Widget

Tags: flutter-web

Need a Calendar Widget inside Stateful widget.
when i triggered DatePicker widget its show like a Dialog widget (ref below image)

[image]

but i need widget inside the stateful instead of overlay popup widget need inside it (ref below image)

[image]

can anyone help me out :

i tried using flutter_calendar_carousel plugin but in that plugin changing of year is a Big challenge .